# Android Storage and Security

Tags: android, file, security

I am developing an android app which I have to store data in files, for doing this I am saving the data in internal memory and I am creating them via this

```
FileOutputStream file = context.openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

this will create a file in internal storage and I think android itself secure this data and whole package of my application by blocking any access to them, but if user selects this app to move to SD card (when internal memory gets full) then

1. Does android moves the file with MODE_PRIVATE to SD card or not?
2. Should I encrypt my files content when saving it ?

Since the data volume which my app involved with is big enough to reduce speed, I prefer to avoid encrypting contents and rely on android security .
could you please advise what should I do or what is the best scenario in this situation ?

Tanks

Answer (score 0):

Encryption is **extremely fast**,  I am not sure why performance for such a simple operation would be a concern in the 21st century.  The problem is that the user or a malicious app can access the file system,  and more importantly anyone can decompile your app or access your app's memory in order to gain the encryption key or the plaintext contents of a "protected" file.

The problem isn't android security, the problem is what you are asking will always be impossible.